# how to post-version control releases with git

Tags: git, version-control

I have a little side-project, maintaining its version control with Git. 
The term version control here refers to its simplest form you can imagine: 
producing commits after each other on only the master branch and at the end of the day, pushing all the commits to the remote.
So far so good. It was sufficient to have only a master branch because the latest state of the application was required all the time.

Then the procurer told me that they need v1.1 and v1.2. The problem is that the latest master commit contains all the things for v1.1 and some undone things for v1.2.

My first intention was to find the base commit where the two 'functionality-pack' is diverged.
I created two branches from that commit and I started to cherry-pick the commits above the base one by one. Fortunately there was not too many of them.
This resulted in two branches (v1.1 and v1.2) holding the appropriate things in place except I had to rebase v1.2 onto v1.1 since the functionality in v1.1 also needed in v1.2

After all of this, I have the following history:

[image]

As you can see, I have a 'dangling' branch which is the master, actually, but I don't need those commits because all of them were cherry-picked to the right place.

The question simply is: how to handle this kind of situation elegantly (basically removing those unnecessary commits) without doing any harm or is there any other way I would have accomplished the same result?

Comment: The Mercurial VCS project uses a separate 'stable' branch where all the commits intended for the next release version are merged into. Any fixes intended for the released version are committed to that 'stable' branch, and eventually merged into trunk (or the 'default' branch). All the new, possibly backward-incompatible, changes are committed to trunk. (Please note: I'm *not* suggesting to use Hg; I'm informing the user part of how their workflow is.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a really good talk on this at ThatConference this year (slide deck available at link):  http://www.thatconference.com/sessions/speaker_188  The presenter had exactly this problem and described how she solved it with git.

Basically, you really shouldn't work in the workflow you described to achieve what you want.  A better way is to have each branch on your repository represent individual features.  Then you bundle those features together in a merge commit to master or a merged branch, and tag that with your version number.

As unhelpful as that sounds (obviously you've already created your history with your current workflow), it might be useful for the future.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for that and i hope i have unterstand it correctly is a `git rebase`

Here are some informations about [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) a branch.

Another cool solution to get a workflow you should take a look at [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow).

Comment: +1 for gitflow. But you forgot to link the main article: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you see that this is not an ideal situation to be in. Not to worry though—the solution is quite simple.

It would be nice to be able to just take out an axe and just start chopping of that big line of divergent commits on master and then merge your work back into master. Unfortunately, I doubt that would go over very well with any co-workers as this would cause a conflict (perhaps even a literal one) when they try to merge their changes into the master branch. So instead of re-writing history, it is best to make a **new commit**.

1. First move to the master branch by running `git checkout master`.
2. Then, from the root of your project, run `git checkout -f <commit> .` where `<commit>` represents the SHA hash of the commit with the message "active pst color changed in measure list cell renderer" (e.g. something that looks similar to: `7cd052c`). Notice the dot at the end which says to check out the version of the current directory from the commit specified.
3. The last step changed the files in your working directory to reflect the state they were in at the common ancestor where the divergence started. Now, let's commit that with `git commit -a`.
4. At this point you should be able to merge back into master without any conflicts: `git merge v12`.

From now on, you can merge any additional changes that you make into the master branch!